# Trying to use first 23 rows of a Pandas data frame as headers and then pivot on the headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pulling in the data frame using tabula.  Unfortunately, the data is arranged in rows as below.  I need to take the first 23 rows and use them as column headers for the remainder of the data.  I need each row to contain these 23 headers for each of about 60 clinics.

```
                                         Col  \
0                                       Date   
1                                     Clinic   
2                                   Location   
3                             Clinic Manager   
4                                 Lease Cost   
5                             Square Footage   
6                           Lease Expiration   
8                              Care Provided   
9                 # of Providers (Full Time)   
10                    # FTE's Providing Care   
11                   # Providers (Part-Time)   
12                    Patients seen per week   
13  Number of patients in rooms per provider   
14        Number of patients in waiting room   
15                              # Exam Rooms   
16                           Procedure rooms   
17                               Other rooms   
18                             Specify other   
20                               Other data:   
21                                 TI Needs:   
23              Conclusion  & Recommendation   
24                                      Date   
25                                    Clinic   
26                                  Location   
27                            Clinic Manager   
28                                Lease Cost   
29                            Square Footage   
30                          Lease Expiration   
32                             Care Provided   
33                # of Providers (Full Time)   
34                    # FTE's Providing Care   
35                   # Providers (Part-Time)   
36                    Patients seen per week   
37  Number of patients in rooms per provider   
38        Number of patients in waiting room   
39                              # Exam Rooms   
40                           Procedure rooms   
41                               Other rooms   
42                             Specify other   
44                               Other data:   
45                                 TI Needs:   
47              Conclusion  & Recommendation   

                                                  Val  
0                                           9/13/2017  
1                                 Gray Medical Center  
2                 1234 E. 164th Ave Thornton CA 12345  
3                                            Jane Doe  
4                      $23,074.80 Rent, $5,392.88 CAM  
5                                               9,840  
6                                           7/31/2023  
8                                     Family Medicine  
9                                                  12  
10                                                 14  
11                                                  1  
12                                                750  
13                                                  4  
14                                                  2  
15                                                 31  
16                                                  1  
17                     X-Ray, Phlebotomist/blood draw  
18                                                NaN  
20  Facilities assistance needed.  50% of business...  
21  Paint and Carpet (flooring is in good conditio...  
23  Lay out and occupancy flow are good for this p...  
24                                          9/13/2017  
25                                    Main Cardiology  
26               12000 Wall St Suite 13 Main CA 12345  
27                                           John Doe  
28                       $9610.42 Rent, $2,937.33 CAM  
29                                              4,406  
30                                          5/31/2024  
32                                         Cardiology  
33                                                  2  
34                                       11, 2 - P.T.  
35                                                  2  
36                                                188  
37                                                  0  
38                                                  2  
39                                                  6  
40                                                  0  
41  1 - Pacemaker, 1 - Treadmill, 1- Echo, 1 - Ech...  
42  Nurse Office, MA station, Reading Room, 2 Phys...  
44  Occupied in Emerus building. Needs facilities ...  
45                    New build out, great condition.  
47  Practice recently relocated from 84th and Alco...
```

I was able to get my data frame in a better place by fixing the headers.  I'm re-posting the first 3 "groups" of data to better illustrate the structure of the data frame.  Everything repeats (headers and values) for each clinic.

Comment: `df=df.T; df=df.set_index(df.columns[:23]).T`?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I'm getting the following error when I run your code:  ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 2 rows, received array of length 23

Comment: Is there anyone else who could weigh in on this or any further clarification needed?

Comment: Is each data in its own frame? and are you sure the data for each is exactly the same length?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I know that right now, Date is being pulled in as the index and it really should be just one of the columns.  Once that's resolved, I have roughly 60 columns identical to the 2nd grouping above that need to be converted to one row per clinic.  The 1st grouping would be used as the headers and I want to end up with 60+ rows with 24 columns (if you add date).

Comment: To answer your question, this is all contained in a single data frame at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[23:].values.reshape(-1, 23),
                   columns=df[:23][0])
print(df2)
```

Ideally the number 23 is the number of columns in each row for the result df . you can replace it with the desired number of columns you want.

Comment: Thanks, David.  I'm getting the following error:  ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2640 into shape (23)

Comment: I just re-posted more of the output to help illustrate the current structure of the data frame.

Comment: I guess you are missing few rows here. The number of rows you are trying to reshape must be a multiple of 23. As per the error message you have 2640 rows which is not divisible by 23. I am assuming you are missing one row here because 2641 is divisible by 23. Can you re-validate your dataset?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have removed null rows from the data frame.  I now have a total of 1176 rows, with 21 rows per group for a total of 56 groups.

Comment: So this seems to be working for now, due in large part to your input. Thank you! It aint pretty, but here it is: df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all') df=df.reset_index(drop=True) df.columns = ['Col', 'Val'] headers=df[0:21].T.iloc[0] df3=df.Val df3=pd.DataFrame(df3.values.reshape(-1,21), columns=headers)

Comment: Yes. Maybe there is a better way to do this. Glad I was able to help in some way!!